# Windows XP IE Enhanced Security Configuration

Tags: windows-xp

It isn't in add/remove and as far as I can see there is no GPO. How on earth do I turn it off, logged in as administrator?

IE8 SP3 XP.

Comment: You did not describe the actual problem your having enough to answer. this "enhanced security" stuff to the USER is just putting things into different Zones, and locking it down.  like sites on restriced zones, and local sites having less restrictions.  for more and better info see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815141

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/307926/enable-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-via-registry